# Network not working in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 10.04, atheros

I have a motherboard with an Atheros R8161 network interface card, running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit with 3.2.0-030200-generic kernel.

I've built and installed the alx drivers from linuxfoundation.com.

After installation, the NIC shows up at eth2 according to ifconfig.

I've then also included the following lines in /etc/network to configure the interface

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

However, even after these steps, I'm still getting a "ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready" in dmesg.

Additionally, in dmesg, udev renamed eth0 to eth2.

My router detects a link with a lit port LED when the NIC is connected to my router though, but I can't ping it.

I've also tried installing a really old PCI NIC and it got detected as eth3 upon bootup without any intervention, but I still can't ping the router.

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These suggestions assume you are using the Gnome desktop environment.

Try using the Network Manager UI to manage the interfaces instead of editing the */etc/network/interfaces* configuration file directly, and assign a static IP address to the interface through that UI.

The package name is *network-manager-gnome* if you need to find and install it.

Ref URL: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/network-manager-gnome

Now, these screenshots below are from my box which is running 12.04 LTS but, from what I can see in the links, 10.04 LTS is no different.

Once you've done that, you can check the interfaces's configuration with *ifconfig* from a terminal and then see if you can ping the gateway address which I expect will be your router's IP address.

It's worth mentioning, for the sake of it having been said, to make sure the netmask is correct i.e. the same netmask as your router.

[image: Wired Ethernet interface]

On my LAN, the gateway address shown (below) is my router's IP address; the router also serves DNS to the LAN which is why this IP address is also shown as a DNS server.

If you aren't sure if you have a DNS server on your LAN, you can use Google's DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4.

If you can ping your gateway address, and get a response, you can use *dig google.com* from a terminal to see if you're getting name resolution.

If that all works, you've verified you have network and internet connectivity and can assume that it's the DHCP server that is not providing an IP address (at least in this case).

[image: IPv4 Settings]

Leland Kristie